# Only update non empty struct fields in golang

Tags: go

Is there an easy way to only update non-nil/empty fields in go(-lang)?

Given these two structs:

```
type UserAccount struct {
    Id         string `json:"id" binding:"required"`
    Enrolled   bool   `json:"enrolled" binding:"required"`
    Email      string `json:"email" binding:"required"`
    GivenName  string `json:"given_name" binding:"required"`
    FamilyName string `json:"family_name" binding:"required"`
    PictureURL string `json:"picture" binding:"required"`
    Nickname   string `json:"nickname" binding:"required"`
}
type ProfilePayload struct {
    Email      string `json:"email,omitempty"`
    GivenName  string `json:"given_name,omitempty"`
    FamilyName string `json:"family_name,omitempty"`
    PictureURL string `json:"picture,omitempty"`
    Nickname   string `json:"nickname,omitempty"` 
}
```

Is it possible to only update non-nil fields in an UserAccount struct. For example, all fields except Email are nil/empty in a ProfilePayload, is there an easy way to "merge" them together and only set the Email field in a UserAccount to a new value and keeping everything else in the UserAccount the same?

```
if payload.Email != "" {
    account.Email = payload.Email
}
....
```

Isn´t really an option for me.

Comment: Why is the conditional you mention not an option?

Comment: Because I want to do it with quite large structs and there has to be a better solution.

Comment: The only way to do it without explicitly checking every field is with reflection. See https://golang.org/pkg/reflect.

Answer (score 2):

What if you just restructured your code

```
type ProfilePayload struct {
    Email      string `json:"email,omitempty"`
    GivenName  string `json:"given_name,omitempty"`
    FamilyName string `json:"family_name,omitempty"`
    PictureURL string `json:"picture,omitempty"`
    Nickname   string `json:"nickname,omitempty"` 
}
type UserAccount struct {
    Id         string `json:"id" binding:"required"`
    Enrolled   bool   `json:"enrolled" binding:"required"`
    ProfilePayload //now it has all the fields from ProfilePayload
}
```

When decoding to json you just decode it to UserAccount, and then you can extract ProfilePayload from UserAccount if you want